# ABCPDF 6 Component Problem - Output Printing Small

Tags: .net, abcpdf

We're using the ABCPDF Version 6 component to create PDF's from ASP .NET. The output works fine the majority of the time but will suddenly switch to small output i.e. the content get's condensed to 1/8th of it's original size.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted websupergoo the makers of abcpdf who responded quickly with the following...

> "These scaling issues can arise when someone remotely logs into your
>   server and changes the screen resolution, out from under Internet
>   Explorer and ABCpdf. Our newer versions of ABCpdf handle this
>   situation better."

I can confirm this is the problem in our situation RDP'ing to the server with different resolutions can effect the output of the abcpdf component. More detailed information on the problem is as follows.

> "On some machines we see interactions between the video driver and
>   MSHTML. On these machines MSHTML doesn't like the screen resolution
>   changing and can change the way it handles content if this happens.
>   Typically this occurs when someone logs onto the machine either
>   locally or remotely using a different screen resolution."

As a resolution to our problem we are going to include in our code a check for the desktop resolution, if it has changed the service will be restarted. websupergoo provided us with some sample code for checking the resolution, the code is property of websupergoo so unfortunately I can't post here.

I hope the info above helps others with the same problem.